# Do we Need to refresh the page to display the proper information after AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

After I clicked on the Remove from Cart, the javascript is deleting the product from the Cart table in the database but it seems not to refresh properly the view on the screen.   I read somewhere when we are using AJAX we need to control the page refresh after it coming back.  Is it the case ?
Which code I am missing to refresh the page properly here ?

Thanks for sharing your input.

Here is what my output looks like after the remove from Cart has been clicked:

```
 Details of Cart:

 Checkout >>
 -----------

 TV HD Toshiba has been removed from your shopping cart.

 Product         Price(unit) Quantity
 TV HD Toshiba   944.99       1        Remove from Cart   <== this line should be remove ?
 --------------                        ----------------   <== this line should be remove ?       
 Total                                 0                  <== this line should be remove
```

This is want I wanted it should return

```
 Details of Cart:

 Checkout >>
 -----------

 TV HD Toshiba has been removed from your shopping cart.

 Product         Price(unit) Quantity

 Total                                 0
```

Index.cshtml

```
 @model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

 @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
 }
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('.RemoveLink').click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/Panier/RemoveFromCart',
                 data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
                 type: 'POST',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (result) {
                    $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                    $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + result.CartCount + ')');
                    $('#update-message').text(result.Message);
                    $('#cart-total').text(result.CartTotal);
                 },
                 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                 alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
             });
             return false;
         });
     });
 </script>
 <h3>
    <em>Details</em> du panier:
 </h3>
 <p class="button">
     @Html.ActionLink("Checkout >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
 </p>  
 <div id="update-message">
 </div>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Produit
        </th>
        <th>
            Prix (unitaire)
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantite
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
    {
       <tr id="row-@item.ProduitId">
           <td>
              @Html.ActionLink(item.Produit.Description,"Details", "Produit", new { id = 
                      item.ProduitId }, null)
           </td>
           <td>
               @item.Produit.Prix
           </td>
           <td id="item-count-@item.PanierId">
               @item.Quantite
           </td>
           <td>
             <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.PanierId"> Enlever du panier </a>    
           </td>
       </tr>
    }
    <tr>
      <td>
          Total
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="cart-total">
          @Model.CartTotal
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Here is the Google PF12 Network RemoveFromCart.  This means the Javascript ran successfully I think.
Preview

```
 {Message:TV HD Toshiba glove has been removed from your shopping cart., CartTotal:0, 
     CartCount:0,..}
 CartCount: 0
 CartTotal: 0
 DeleteId: 31
 ItemCount: 0
 Message: "TV HD Toshiba has been removed from your shopping cart."
```

Response

```
  {"Message":"TV HD Toshiba has been removed from your shopping 
         cart.","CartTotal":0,"CartCount":0,"ItemCount":0,"DeleteId":31}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to refresh the whole page, that would defeat the whole point of using AJAX in the first place. What you should do is manipulate the DOM in Javascript in the `success` handler for your AJAX call to change or remove whatever elements are now stale.

Comment: @MattBurland Thanks for your answer, can you have an example for me to understand what is missing.  I looked at the MVC Music store and my AJAX seems to be identical, I guess I am missing the part do remove the row from the screen but I can't find what is missing. Any idea?

Comment: Difficult to see without your rendered HTML, but in your `<tr id="row-@item.ProduitId">`, you need to identify the row that was removed (it looks like your response includes the `DeleteId` and hopefully that maps to a specific row somehow, presumably it's something like `id="row-31"`) and simple remove it from your table with something like `$("#row-31").remove()`

Comment: I tried to add this in the javascript before or after the .fadeout('slow')  ==>    $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).remove();  but it didn't change anything. Means the row still on the screen, it is not refresh.  Can you tell me which code you need to diagnostic the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Move your logic for rendering the table into a partial razor view then call it by using the following HTML Helper.  @Html.Partial("CartTable").

Update your success ajax handler to make another ajax call to the server to retrieve this partial view and then update your DOM with the results.

```
     @model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

 @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
 }
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('.RemoveLink').click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/Panier/RemoveFromCart',
                 data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
                 type: 'POST',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (result) {
                    $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                    $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + result.CartCount + ')');
                    $('#update-message').text(result.Message);
                    $('#cart-total').text(result.CartTotal);
                    $.get("url").done( function(data){ $("#ContentTable).html(data); } );
                 },
                 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                 alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
             });
             return false;
         });
     });
 </script>
 <h3>
    <em>Details</em> du panier:
 </h3>
 <p class="button">
     @Html.ActionLink("Checkout >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
 </p>  
 <div id="update-message">
 </div>
 <div id="table-content">
  @Html.Partial("TableContent")
</div>
```

Comment: When I go to my PanierController at the ActionResult RemoveFromCart right click add View , Should we select create a stronly-typed view? When I am using partial view, the only line I have is @model Tp1WebStore3.Models.Panier,  can you provide me more input please

Comment: I got an error 404 Not Found  with the $.get("url").done( function(data){ $("#TableContent").html(data); } );  Any idea ?  My partial view is called TableContent.cshtml as per my div-id="table-content">

Comment: I tried this, got no error but didn't refresh the page successfully (ie the deleted row is still appearing in the page $.get("/Panier").done(function (data) { $("#TableContent").html(data); });

Comment: Create a new controller action, say TableView.  Inside that action too should return something like Partial(#TableContent).  Change "URL" in the js function to match your controller action.

Comment: Is your controller action updating the model?

Comment: When you are saying updating the model, do you means if the database is updated by my code ?